# How to get variable unique identification number or string

Tags: python

Using

```
a=7
print hex(id(a))
```

getting back:

```
0x7f866b425e58
```

Intending to use this output (converted to string) as an identification number for each class object declared I need to make sure it would stay the same while the program is running. I also need to know if a second character is always 'x' (on mac, win and linux). If I am making a bad choice choosing `hex(id))` please let me know what would be a better option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`id()` is guaranteed to be stable for the lifetime of the object, **but** the identifier can be reused if the object is destroyed.

The `0x` prefix is always going to be there when using `hex()`. You could also use `format(..., 'x')` to format to a hex number *without* a prefix:

```
>>> a = 7 
>>> print format(id(a), 'x')
7f866b425e58
```

You'd be better of just using a [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to produce your unique ids, perhaps with a prefix or by negating the number if you need to distinguish these from others:

```
from itertools import count

id_counter = count()
```

and each time you need a new id, use:

```
next(id_counter)
```

and store this as an attribute on your instances. You can make the `count()` count *down* by giving it a negative step:

```
id_counter = count(-1, -1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> id_counter = count(-1, -1)
>>> next(id_counter)
-1
>>> next(id_counter)
-2
```

Comment: I like an idea of using itertools.count()! Thanks! That's a great one! Actually I was already using negative numbers to distinguish the objects that were not yet written to database. It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at hash(obj) https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one). Hash values are
>   integers. They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a
>   dictionary lookup. Numeric values that compare equal have the same
>   hash value (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1
>   and 1.0).

Comment: Hash identifies a *value*, and not uniquely. The OP wants to identify *specific objects*.

Comment: OP said "...I need to make sure it would stay the same while the program is running...". I wasn't 100% sure if he wanted identity or value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But is that really what the OP needs? This smells to me like an [XY question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @jamessan: I agree it'd be helpful for the OP to clarify their usecase.

Comment: All the object instances are database entities. Each has an assigned by database unique id number. Another group of such instances are the ones that were declared but not yet written to database (no database id number yet). An entire code designed around the unique id numbers. The instances with no ids (unpublished ones) fall out of the entire design. So I need to be able to substitute yet-not-existent database ids with the fake ones.

Comment: @user590028 but even for values the hash isn't *unique*.

Comment: @Sputnix: I'm not sure `id()` is a good choice then as the values are reused if your objects are removed at some point.

Comment: @Sputnix That is important information that should be in your question.  It sounds like there's a larger design problem here if the code is requiring all data objects to have an id that doesn't conflict with an existing id in the database, even though not all data is yet in the database.

Comment: Unique ids are great way to keep things organized (I can even use them as the dictionary keys). It is not that burden to make sure each object has an unique id. The program itself kind of "mimics" what database does where things just can't exist without ids